# Paddle Integration - Content Security Policy Issue

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway, payment, paddle

I'm trying to integrate Paddle as the payment method into my Vue app.

I inserted the official Paddle CDN link into the index, as shown below:

```
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.paddle.com/paddle/v2/paddle.js"></script>
</head>
```

Then, I created a subscribe.vue page and added the 'subscribe' button as shown below:

```
<script setup lang="ts">

var vendorId = parseInt(import.meta.env.VITE_GLOB_PADDLE_VENDOR_ID)

if (import.meta.env.VITE_GLOB_PADDLE_SANDBOX_ENV == "true") {
    Paddle.Environment.set("sandbox");
}

Paddle.Setup({
    seller: vendorId // replace with your seller ID 
});

const onSubscribe = () => {
    Paddle.Checkout.open({
        settings: {
            displayMode: "overlay",
            theme: "light",
            locale: "en"
        },
        items: [
            {
                priceId: 'pri_01haxcpg4m4e5m067mghbjk7r8',
                quantity: 1
            },
            {
                priceId: 'pri_01haxcp3m43vmna28whxr0qe7v',
                quantity: 1
            }
        ],
    });
}

</script>

<template>

    <VBtn @click="onSubscribe">Subscribe</VBtn>

</template>
```

I followed Paddle's instructions and added 'https://localhost' to the default payment link. (Initially, I added 'http://localhost' but it was automatically changed to 'https'. I'm not sure if this is the reason for the error.)

However, when I click the subscribe button, an issue arises. Please check the screenshot here:

[image]